# Pandas SUMIF equivalent for two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame(df1) that looks like this with a store and startdate/enddate for each one:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'store': ['X','Y','Z'], 'startdate': ['2020-02-03', '2020-03-05', '2020-04-01'], 'enddate': ['2020-03-05', '2020-05-02', '2020-06-07']})
df1
```

And I have a second DataFrame (df2) that looks like this and has invoice records for the different stores:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'store': ['X','X','X','Y','Y'], 'invoicedate': ['2020-01-03','2020-02-05','2020-03-04', '2020-05-01', '2020-04-04'], 'sales': [153, 156, 12, 42, 48],})
df2
```

I want to add a column, we can call it df1['totalsales'], to the first DataFrame (df1) that sums up df2['sales'] when...

1. `df1['store']=df2['store']`
2. `df2['invoicedate'] >= df1['startdate'] **&** df2['invoicedate'] <= df1['enddate']`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Chances are slim that people just start coding for you. Please post your coding attempts as a [mre] and explain what is not working, then people may be willing to help you fix your code.

Comment: @Ronald Thank you! Sorry, I'm still a newbie. I thought the above was most helpful in explaining my problem since I knew my code was wrong, but I will keep this in mind. Appreciate you calling this out.

Comment: Great, and I see you've got some answers now too, so it worked out well ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to keep all of the rows in `df1`, you could use this:

```
def get_total_sales(x):
    mask = df2.store == x.store
    mask &= df2.invoicedate > x.startdate
    mask &= df2.invoicedate <= x.enddate
    x['total_sales'] = df2[mask].sales.sum()
    return x
df1.apply(lambda x: get_total_sales(x), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
store   startdate     enddate  total_sales
    X  2020-02-03  2020-03-05          168
    Y  2020-03-05  2020-05-02           90
    Z  2020-04-01  2020-06-07            0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to do. Greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

#### Update easy fix:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='store').query('startdate <= invoicedate <= enddate')\
 .groupby(['store', 'startdate', 'enddate'])[['sales']].sum()\
 .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1), fill_value=0)\
 .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  store   startdate     enddate  sales
0     X  2020-02-03  2020-03-05    168
1     Y  2020-03-05  2020-05-02     90
2     Z  2020-04-01  2020-06-07      0
```

---

IIUC, let's use `merge` and `query` to filter results then `groupby` with `sum`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='store').query('startdate <= invoicedate <= enddate')\
   .groupby(['store', 'startdate', 'enddate'])[['sales']].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  store   startdate     enddate  sales
0     X  2020-02-03  2020-03-05    168
1     Y  2020-03-05  2020-05-02     90
```

Comment: Thank you! I should've clarified that I'd like to keep all the rows in df1, but this is perfect if I want to exclude non-matches. Might need this later. Really appreciate it.