# Building a new Pandas DataFrame based on dates from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My title is not great because I'm having trouble articulating my question. Basically, I have a DateFrame with transactional data consisting of a few DateTime columns and a value column. I need to apply filters to the dates and sum the resulting values in a new DataFrame.

Here is a simplified version of my DateFrame `df`:

```
    Sched Week  Ship Week   Ready Week  vals
0   2021-01-04  2021-01-11  2021-01-04  10
1   2021-01-04  2021-01-11  2021-01-04  10
2   2021-01-04  2021-01-04  2021-01-04  2
3   2021-01-07  2021-01-18  2021-01-04  9
4   2021-01-12  2021-01-18  2021-01-11  1
5   2021-01-13  2021-01-11  2021-01-11  6
6   2021-01-13  2021-01-11  2021-01-11  4
7   2021-01-13  2021-01-25  2021-01-11  8
8   2021-01-15  2021-01-25  2021-01-18  4
9   2021-01-19  2021-01-25  2021-01-18  5
10  2021-01-19  2021-01-25  2021-01-18  6
11  2021-01-21  2021-01-25  2021-01-18  10
12  2021-01-21  2021-01-25  2021-01-18  6
```

The new DataFrame `df_result` I want to create should look like this based on the values in df. The `Sched Week` column in this DataFrame is simply `df['Sched Week'].unique()` and foo is the sum of `df['values']` for the rows that meet the conditions below.

```
    Sched Week  foo
0   2021-01-04  20
1   2021-01-07  29
2   2021-01-12  10
3   2021-01-13  18
4   2021-01-15  18
5   2021-01-19  23
6   2021-01-21  39
```

And here is the basic logic to generate the new DataFrame:

```
df['Sched Week'] <= df_result['Sched Week'] &
df['Ship Week'] > df_result['Sched Week'] &
df['Ready Week'] <= df_result['Sched Week']
```

This test needs to be performed for **each row** in the new `df_result` DataFrame and the values summed.

So, the 20 at index 0 is the sum of the values at index 0 and 1 from the original `df`, since those rows meet the conditions for 2021-01-04.

I have tried every way to boolean mask and groupby that I can think of but nothing I've done so far has worked.

**EDIT**

Here is the equivalent in Excel.

The formula in cell J3 is `=SUMIFS(F:F,C:C,"<="&I3,D:D,">"&I3,E:E,"<="&I3)`

[DataFrames represented in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7EQt.png)

Comment: @sammywemmy I was attempting to explain the conditions with those inequalities. In Excel terms this is just a SUMIFS formula with three conditions. I also double checked the value for ```2021-01-19``` it is correct. It is the sum of values at index 7-10 because that is where all three of the date conditions are True.

Comment: edited my question to show the solution in Excel

Comment: the table on the right ```df_result``` is the one I want to create from the one on the left ```df```. And ```df_result['Sched Week'] = df['Sched Week'].unique()```.

Comment: An accurate title would be ***"Aggregate dataframe values by 'Scheduled Week', 'Ship Week', 'Ready Week'"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept digging and found a solution to my question with a lot of help from this [answer from kait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923267/pandas-sumif-equivalent-for-two-dataframes)

```
def usr(x):
    mask = df['Sched Week'] <= x['Sched Week']
    mask &= df['Ship Week'] > x['Sched Week']
    mask &= df['Ready Week'] <= x['Sched Week']
    x['foo'] = df[mask].vals.sum()
    return x

df_result.apply(lambda x: usr(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: efficient as well, since all the steps within the function are vectorized

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an inequality join to get the relevant rows, sum the values with a groupby before merging back to the original dataframe. The [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) offers an efficient implementation for non-equi joins - under the hood it uses binary search, which is faster/bettern than iterating through every row (a cartesian join) - this becomes even more evident for large data:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r'\s{2,}', 
                       engine='python', 
                       parse_dates = ['Sched Week', 'Ship Week', 'Ready Week'])

dff = df['Sched Week'].drop_duplicates()

(df
.conditional_join(
    dff, 
    ('Sched Week', 'Sched Week', '<='), 
    ('Ship Week', 'Sched Week', '>'), 
    ('Ready Week', 'Sched Week', '<='), 
    how = 'right', 
    df_columns='vals')
.groupby('Sched Week', sort=False, as_index=False)
.sum(numeric_only=True)
)
  Sched Week  vals
0 2021-01-04    20
1 2021-01-07    29
2 2021-01-12    10
3 2021-01-13    18
4 2021-01-15    18
5 2021-01-19    23
6 2021-01-21    39
```